# Can't allow a new user to run Cassandra nodetool command

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

So I would like to allow an additional user account to be able to run Cassandra commands, such as nodetool status, etc.  This account is not the account under which Cassandra runs.

I have a four node cluster, and the installation was done via tarball.  I have the path set and everything looks to be in order.  For three of the nodes everything works fine, but on the fourth node everytime I try to run nodetool I get the following error:  Cannot determine CASSANDRA_BIN.

No matter what I try on this node, I get the same problem.  To verify the issue isn't this specific account I've tried creating a new user, adding it to the necessary group (so permissions aren't an issue) and giving it the correct path, and yet again I keep getting the Cannot determine CASSANDRA_BIN.

The user under which Cassandra runs is fine on this node, I'm just wondering what could be causing this issue.  It seems that everything is identical to the other 3 nodes, however I guess something has to be different here (I did not build this cluster so I don't know if something weird was done with this node that wasn't with the others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script that generates that error attempts to determine the location of CASSANDRA_BIN by looking for the **cassandra** script in one of **$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin**, **/usr/bin** or **/usr/sbin**.

So for this to fail the user attempting to launch nodetool either doesn't have read permissions to one or all of those locations or the **cassandra** script doesn't exist at any of those locations.

Comment: Yep I have verified that the permissions are correct.  Also the Cassandra script location is correct because the user that actually runs Cassandra can execute all commands just fine.  In fact, if I go to the $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin directory and run the ./nodetool command it works fine for the original user, and every other user gives me that Cannot determine CASSANDRA_BIN error despite the users having rx permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the culprit, it turns out there was permissions issue in the directory where the cassandra executable actually lives for some reason had all the necessary executables permissions set to read only for all users other than the user that we use to actually run Cassandra.

Thanks!